# Controlling power to a raspberry pi with relay or MOSFETs

Tags: power, relay, alternative-power

So I have a 12V battery connected to a (5v/6v optional) UBEC powering the pi through the GPIO pins.

Using a separate circuit, probably with a micro-controller, I want to be able to toggle power to the pi, giving it enough time to shut off when needed.

I've read articles where they recommend using a latching relay controlled by separate logic as a low power way to switch on power and give it time to shut off. Is it possible to use Power MOSFETs connected to the UBEC to switch power on to the raspberry pi, or is it better to simply stick to the relay?

Comment: You could use a P-channel MOSFET to control power. The DMG2305UX used on the Pi should be suitable.

Comment: You're pretty brave using a UBEC to power the Pi *via the GPIO pins*.

Comment: @Cunningham'sLawyer why? Would you just need some polarity and current protection?

Comment: @LukeMoll `Polarity, current protection, voltage stability, electrical noise, electrical ripple, EMI (to an extent), ...` I could go on. You're basically bypassing all the power input protection built into the Pi. And who knows the quality of the UBEC OP is using. I got a cheap UBEC from China that fried an *Arduino*, yet is of the right voltage. A Pi is a bit more sensitive.

Comment: @Cunningham'sLawyer Good point, I'll wire it up to a micro usb cable, probably using something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1390)